# Add 0 if day is lesser than 9 in sql

Tags: sql, datepart

I have the following value:

```
Jun **6** 2012 12:00:00:000AM
```

What I want is:

```
Jun **06** 2012 12:00:00:000AM
```

`0` should only be prepended if the value of day is less than `9`.

How do I do this?

Comment: Use Case statement. What database you are using.

Comment: You need to supply a lot more context than that: what's the RDBMS, what's the table definition, what's the query that returns the string, and so on.

Comment: Which Sql? Is that output from a SELECT?

Comment: You should just use approaite date format, eg. in MySQL use `%d` in [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: Date types aren't formatted in any specific way. A format is used only when you convert them to strings. Where are you doing this conversion? On the server, the client?

Comment: Your SQL should return a date value and the user interface of your app should format appropriately.

Comment: A better solution then a `Case` statement would be to format DateTime.ToString to match what you need exactly.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using SQL Server you can do:

```
DECLARE @dt datetime = '1/1/2012'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), @dt, 107) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @dt, 114)
```

Answer (score 0):

In any database, you can do something like:

```
(case when substring(val, 5, 1) = ' '
      then substring(val, 1, 4)||'0'+substring(val, 5, 1000)
      else val
 end)
```

This checks for the 5th character to see if it is a space.  If so, then a zero needs to be added.  I'm assuming the "**" are for emphasis an not in the string.

The problem is that the various string operators -- substring and concatenation -- tend to vary by database.